# ActiveAdmin app migration to Rails 4 crashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

We have an app that we're upgrading from Rails 3.2.x to Rails 4.1.12.  There have been a ton of issues that we've already resolved, but this one I haven't got figured out yet.  When we load the ActiveAdmin index page we get the following error:

```
undefined method `call' for #<Pano::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fa1aeb50778>
Extracted source (around line #2):
1

  insert_tag active_admin_application.view_factory["page"]

Rails.root: /Users/user/Google Drive/Code/app/app-rails

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/admin/dashboard.rb:32:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
app/admin/dashboard.rb:31:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
app/admin/dashboard.rb:30:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
app/admin/dashboard.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The page causing the error is a default ActiveAdmin page:

/activeadmin/app/views/page/index.html.arb

I completed all the steps on the ActiveAdmin site for upgrading to Rails 4, but I can't seem to find a fix for this.  Appreciate any thoughts or guidance.

Comment: Without code, no one is really able to help you. We need full source of `Pano` model, of `page/index.html.arb` and `admin/dashboard.rb`

Comment: Provide the line for active_admin in your gemfile

Comment: I was able to get past this issue, by using Rails 4.2.3 instead of Rails 4.1.12.  The issue I was having did not manifest itself in the newer version.